# Webstorm/PhpStorm - collapse directory tree if there is just one child directory

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

is it possible to set project directory tree in webstorm to autoopen or collapse directory tree when there is just one subdirectory?

So, when directory tree is as bellow and I open parentDir, webstorm will autoOpen directories with one sub directory automatically? Preferably making `parentDir/subDir1/subDir2` a one liner in directory tree.

```
parentDir/
--> subDir1/
----> subDir2/
------> index.html
```

Comment: If you would like this to happen, vote for feature request here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150570

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible - a possibility to flatten directories is not available in WebStorm. Please feel free to file a request for this feature to [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA)

Comment: Thank you, ive created a feature request here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150570